# How to get the header title and display it in another div or span?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to get the header title of the calendar. Issue is with the mobile view, the long title making the view ugly. So i want to show to the title in one row above.

Current view is this:

[image]

and i want the following view

[image]

So, if anyone can let me know how to get the title and append it in some other div/span using jquery. Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: to be honest with you fullCalendar is not really built for mobile in general. The width of the title will be the least of your problems.

Comment: but if you really want to get the title...use your browser's DOM inspector to find out what element it is stored in. Once you know that, assuming you know a little bit of jQuery already then it's trivial to select that element, copy the content, and append it somewhere else. You could also remove it from the original element as well. Have you tried doing any of that yet?

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your valuable help. It works. adding solution as below.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @Adyson, I somehow solved it. Hope this will be helpful for others.

1. Add an element in your desired place(#). the title will be displayed here.
2. In Fullcalendar, I am having the header title in the center. so in html it is in (class .fc-center). I use jQuery to copy and show the title in my selector tag, whenever the dom changes

Code:

```
$("#calendar").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".fc-center", function() {
    loadTitle();
});

function loadTitle(){
   var title = $( ".fc-center" ).html(); 
   $('#calendarTitle').html(title);
}
```